# SVG to display on button click event but how?

Tags: vb.net, svg, textbox, webbrowser-control

I have a textbox with some SVG code written in it and I would like to display it as my actual html page in a WebBrowser once the button click event is triggerd but I can see how to do that.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

 TextBox1.Text = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><svg height=" & Chr(34) & "5000" & Chr(34) & " width=" & Chr(34) & "5000" & Chr(34) & "><g style=" & Chr(34) & "fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:0.1" & Chr(34) & " stroke-dasharray=" & Chr(34) & "40,5,10,5" & Chr(34) & "><line x1=" & Chr(34) & "0" & Chr(34) & " y1=" & Chr(34) & "0" & Chr(34) & " x2=" & Chr(34) & "200" & Chr(34) & " y2=" & Chr(34) & "150" & Chr(34) & "/><line x1=" & Chr(34) & "200" & Chr(34) & " y1=" & Chr(34) & "150" & Chr(34) & " x2=" & Chr(34) & "400" & Chr(34) & " y2=" & Chr(34) & "0" & Chr(34) & "/><polyline points=" & Chr(34) & "0,0 50,50 0,100 50,100 130,150 210,190" & Chr(34) & "/></g></svg></body></html>"

WebBrowser1.Document.Write(TextBox1.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: That stroke is too thin. Go up to `1px` (or `0.5`)-- BTW,  `WebBrowser1.Navigate("") Dim doc  WebBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(True) doc.Write([Your HTML]) WebBrowser1.Refresh()`